# WordPress $wpdb->get_row() Query Won't Work With Variable, But Works With Hardcoded

Tags: wordpress

My code is correct (I've been programming for 13 years), but for some reason when I use a variable in a SELECT query in the WHERE clause, I get no result. If I hardcode it, it works. How could this be? Blowing my mind...

```
$track = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT tracking_id, order_id, outbound_tracking_number, return_tracking_numbers FROM wp_woocommerce_trackingnumbers WHERE order_id = %s", $o_id));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be (`%s` should be `%d`)

```
$track = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT tracking_id, order_id, outbound_tracking_number, return_tracking_numbers FROM wp_woocommerce_trackingnumbers WHERE order_id = %d", $o_id));
```

`%s` for strings and `%d` for digits and variable `$o_id` sounds like an integer to me.

Comment: This worked for me as well, i had even the same variable name and column name, and untill i found this, i was changing column name :D