# passing variable in wpdb query wont work

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have seen this very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004556/wordpress-wpdb-get-row-query-wont-work-with-variable-but-works-with-hardco) however I cannot get mine to work.

```
`<?php

$exerciseID = '4';

global $wpdb;
$query = "
SELECT * 
FROM imagemap
WHERE exercise = $exerciseID";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query); 
foreach($result as $row)
{
echo $row->id."  ".$row->exercise." ".$row->source." <br>";
}

?>
```

Any assistance on getting this variable to work would be great - it works when hard coded.

Comment: what is the data type of exercise ?

Comment: query looks good. try var_dump($result) and see what it gives ?

Comment: var_dump($result) gives me 
    array(0) { }

However if hard coded I get 

array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#311 (6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["exercise"]=> string(1) "1" ["source"]=> string(17) "IMG_5594 copy.jpg" ["position"]=> NULL ["preview"]=> NULL ["display"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#312 (6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["exercise"]=> string(1) "1" ["source"]=> string(17) "IMG_5605 copy.jpg" ["position"]=> string(1) etc etc ....

Comment: change `exercise = $exerciseID"` to `exercise = '$exerciseID'"` OR as `exercise = ".$exerciseID` and see if this works ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - have tried all these variants of the query already.

Comment: how u are getting the value of $exerciseID or u are just hardcoding it ?

Comment: Just hard coding for now during testing, it will be gathered in the loop from the post_ID eventually.

Comment: hmm thats weird and if u manually make the query as `SELECT * FROM imagemap WHERE exercise = '4'` it works ?

Comment: indeed it does - like a charm...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the query !! not sure why it fails. u can try some debuging by echoing the $query and see how it comes.

Comment: that give me " SELECT * FROM imagemap WHERE exercise = '4' array(0) { } "

Comment: this should work there is nothing wrong. Try to see if WP has some error catching functions for DB, this might tell u why on earth its not workin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 $query = "
SELECT * 
FROM imagemap
WHERE exercise = '".$exerciseID."'";
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for trying - this does not work I get the dump of 'SELECT * FROM imagemap WHERE exercise = '4'array(0) { }'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM imagemapWHERE exercise = $exerciseID";
```

try this

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM imagemapWHERE exercise =" . $exerciseID;
```